# Remote IQueryable (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Tell me please if it's possible to use remote IQueryable. My task is to implement repository pattern on server side and make its bridge on the client. After creation the instance of repository I have to transmit it's query (IQueryable) to the client side to let clients perform their queries. After client completes the query and IQueryable.Provider.Execute is called  (I use my own QueryProvider to handle this method), I have to transmit the query back to the server's repository and execute the query.

Here's code:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}

// This class exists on the server side and contains reference to the IQueryable<T>.
// When the expression visits server this class processes it and return the result of the execution.
public class RemoteRepositoryServer<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> Query { get; private set; }

    public RemoteRepositoryServer(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        this.Query = query;
    }

    public object ExecuteExpression(Expression expression)
    {
        return this.Query.Provider.Execute(expression);
    }
}

// This is my bridge repository to the server. Its task is to encapsulate my own query with my own query provider and
// to send expression to the server side the the provider demands.
public class RepositoryClientBridge<T> :
    IRepository<T>
{
    // My own query with my own query provider.
    public Query<T> Query { get; private set; }

    // Reference to the message sender.
    public IRemoteExpressionExecutor ExpressionExecutor { get; private set; }

    public RepositoryClientBridge(
        Expression baseExpression,
        IRemoteExpressionExecutor expressionExecutor)
    {
        // here we instantiate new query with provider that accepts expression callback to process
        this.Query = new Query<T>(new MyQueryProvider(this.ExecuteExpression));
        this.ExpressionExecutor = expressionExecutor;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.Query;
    }

    private object ExecuteExpression(Expression e)
    {
        // Transmit execution to the server and return the result of the expression processing.
        return this.ExpressionExecutor.Execute(e);
    }
}

// Transmits epression to the server and returns result of the execution.
public interface IRemoteExpressionExecutor
{
    object Execute(Expression expression);
}
```

And my question is ho to do that!? I can't use WCF and have to implement it with my own. I've tried to use Serialize.Xml for serial/deseril expressions - it does well, but I can't execute queries. I tried to use it with EnumerableQuery and when I call Execute method with the specified expression I get exception (it's inner ArgumentNullException, somewhere in the depths).
If someone knowns the best way to transmit expressions from the server to the client and back, please help me to solve the problem.

P.S. I'll be using LINQ To EF, XML and Memory (EnumerableQuery).

Comment: I believe OData supports IQueryable transmission... http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options